# How Do I Validate At Compile Time a Java Enum Conforms to Two Different Types

Tags: java, generics, enums, interface

**UPDATE on 2023-10-26:**
Here's a [gist of the example source code](https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/f70cc24e855ab18a2b13f557dbf356d3), which has been refactored to incorporate the solution provided within the [answer provided by @Turing85](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77363041/501113).

---

Given the code listed below across five classes, I have two questions regarding resolving the types at compile time (explicitly NOT at run time).

1. In `DbIdEnumOps` within the private constructor, how can I validate that the `enumClassE` passed also conforms to `Class<EE>`?
2. In `Main` within the `main` method, how do I get `a` to infer where it shows as `Integer`, instead of `Object`, without resorting to `b` where I provide an explicit type hint?

I have spent hours trying different tangents to get this to work. And the code below is as close as I've been able to get.

---

**Class: EnumOps.java**

```java
public final class EnumOps<E extends Enum<E>> {
  private final Class<E> enumClass;
  private final List<E> enumsValues;

  private EnumOps(Class<E> enumClass) {
    this.enumClass = enumClass;
    this.enumsValues = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(enumClass.getEnumConstants()));
  }

  public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumOps<E> from(Class<E> enumClass) {
    return new EnumOps<>(enumClass);
  }

  public Class<E> getEnumClass() {
    return this.enumClass;
  }

  public List<E> toList() {
    return this.enumsValues;
  }

  //omitted lots of other helpful enum utilities that ought to have been provided by the Java compiler by default
}
```

---

**Interface: DbIdEnum.java**

```
public interface DbIdEnum<T> {
  T getDbId();
}
```

---

**Class: DbIdEnumOps.java**

```java
public final class DbIdEnumOps<E extends Enum<E>, EE extends DbIdEnum<T>, T> {
  private final Map<T, E> enumValueByDbId;
  private final Map<String, E> enumValueByNameLowerCaseOrDbId;

  private DbIdEnum<T> toDbIdEnum(E e) {
    return ((DbIdEnum<T>) e);
  }

  public static <E extends Enum<E>, EE extends DbIdEnum<T>, T> DbIdEnumOps<E, EE, T> from(Class<E> enumClassE) {
    return new DbIdEnumOps<>(enumClassE);
  }

  private DbIdEnumOps(Class<E> enumClassE) {
    //how to validate AT COMPILE TIME `enumClassE` also conforms to `Class<EE>`?
    var enumOpsList =
        EnumOps.from(Objects.requireNonNull(enumClassE))
            .toList();
    this.enumValueByDbId =
        Collections.unmodifiableMap(
            enumOpsList
                .stream()
                .map(e -> Map.entry(toDbIdEnum(e).getDbId(), e))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
    this.enumValueByNameLowerCaseOrDbId =
        Collections.unmodifiableMap(
            enumOpsList
                .stream()
                .flatMap(e -> Stream.of(
                    Map.entry(e.name().toLowerCase(), e),
                    Map.entry(toDbIdEnum(e).getDbId().toString(), e)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)));
  }

  public Map<T, E> getEnumValueByDbId() {
    return this.enumValueByDbId;
  }

  public Map<String, E> getEnumValueByNameLowerCaseOrDbId() {
    return this.enumValueByNameLowerCaseOrDbId;
  }
}
```

---

**Enum: TrafficLight.java**

```java
public enum TrafficLight implements DbIdEnum<Integer> {
  GREEN(1),
  YELLOW(2),
  RED(3);

  private final Integer dbId;

  TrafficLight(Integer dbId) {
    this.dbId = dbId;
  }

  private static final EnumOps<TrafficLight> enumOps =
      EnumOps.from(TrafficLight.class);
  private static final DbIdEnumOps<TrafficLight, DbIdEnum<Integer>, Integer> dbIdEnumOpsA =
      DbIdEnumOps.from(TrafficLight.class);

  public static EnumOps<TrafficLight> ops() {
    return enumOps;
  }

  public static DbIdEnumOps<TrafficLight, DbIdEnum<Integer>, Integer> dbIdOps() {
    return dbIdEnumOpsA;
  }

  public Integer getDbId() {
    return this.dbId;
  }
}
```

---

**Class: Main.java**

```java
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //a is inferred as: DbIdEnumOps<TrafficLight, DbIdEnum<Object>, Object>
    var a = DbIdEnumOps.from(TrafficLight.class);
    var b = DbIdEnumOps.<TrafficLight, DbIdEnum<Integer>, Integer>from(TrafficLight.class);
    DbIdEnumOps<TrafficLight, DbIdEnum<Integer>, Integer> c = DbIdEnumOps.from(TrafficLight.class);
    System.out.println("use me to set a breakpoint to examine the contents of the maps");

    //How do I get `a` to infer where it shows as `Integer`, instead of `Object`, without resorting to `b` where I provide an explicit type hint?
  }
}
```

---

For 1, a tangent I took involved passing in the same `enum` class twice to the `from` method where the method's signature looked like this:

```java
  public static <E extends Enum<E>, EE extends DbIdEnum<T>, T> DbIdEnumOps<E, EE, T> from(Class<EE> enumClassEe, Class<E> enumClassE) {
    return new DbIdEnumOps<>(enumClassEe, enumClassE);
  }

  private DbIdEnumOps(Class<EE> enumClassEe, Class<E> enumClassE) {...
```

And while I got that to work, passing the enum in twice didn't look correct just to satisfy both types.

I figure there is some arcane or unusual type specification pathway that remains right outside my understanding. Any guidance with this would be deeply appreciated.

---

**Background:** For those more curious about the context, I am attempting to DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) out a bunch of `enum`s being used across multiple code bases. Many, but not ALL, of the enums are used for database columns. Hence, the explicit (and required) separation of concerns between `EnumOps` and `DbIdEnumOps`.

Comment: `I, E extends Enum<E> & DbIdEnum<I>`?

Comment: "*In `DbIdEnumOps` within the private constructor, how can I validate that the `enumClassE` passed also conforms to `Class<EE>`*" -- this does not make sense.  The type of the argument is `Class<E>`.  It cannot also be a `Class<EE>` unless `E` and `EE` are the same type, in which case you already have what you want.

Comment: @JohnBollinger OP phrased the question a little bit confusing. If I understood OP right, they want to assure that some generic parameter `E` is an enum and implements an interface at the same time.

Comment: @Turing85 That was the freakin trick! Man, a missing ampersand! ARGH! Anyway, if you want to compose an answer that essentially says change to this, `public final class DbIdEnumOps<E extends Enum<E> & DbIdEnum<T>, T> {`, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I think you're talking to Turing85.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can restrict the generic type to comply with multiple implementations through an `&`. If we want some `E` to be an `Enum<E>` and implement some `interface Foo`, we ca write `E extends Enum<E> & Foo`. Of course, `Foo` can also have a generic parameter, which we can either bind (e.g. `E extends Enum<E> & Foo<Integer>`) or introduce an additional generic parameter (`I, E extends Enum<E> & Foo<I>`). Putting it all together, we get:

```
class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    boo(Bar.bar1);
//    foo(new Baz()); // should not work - does not work
//    foo(Bang.bang1); // should not work - does not work
  }

  public static <T extends Enum<T> & Foo<Integer>> void boo(T t) {
    System.out.println(t.ordinal());
    System.out.println(t.foo());
  }
}

interface Foo<T> {
  T foo();
}

enum Bar implements Foo<Integer> {
  bar1(1);

  final int foo;

  Bar(int foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer foo() {
    return foo;
  }
}

class Baz implements Foo<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer foo() {
    return 42;
  }
}

enum Bang {
  bang1
}
```

[<kbd>`Ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/A0PX0l)

Comment: Here's the original code refactored to use your solution: https://gist.github.com/chaotic3quilibrium/f70cc24e855ab18a2b13f557dbf356d3